# How to make the previous/next pages always visible in pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a pagination function and the main class where I initialize this function. I need to make sure that the Previous button and the Next button are always visible, just so that the Previous button is disable on the first page and the Next button on the last. I followed the example from the WordPress documentation. How can I do this?

```php
function paginate_links($args = '')
{
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;

    //...

    if ($args['prev_next'] && $current && 1 < $current):
        $link = str_replace('%_%', 2 == $current ? '' : $args['format'], $args['base']);
        $link = str_replace('%#%', $current - 1, $link);
        if ($add_args) {
            $link = add_query_arg($add_args, $link);
        }
        $link .= $args['add_fragment'];

        $page_links[] = sprintf(
            '<div class="arrow" data-number="%s">
    Previous <
    /div>',
            $current - 1,
            $args['prev_text']
        );
    endif;

    for ($n = 1; $n <= $total; $n++):
        if ($n == $current):
            $page_links[] = sprintf(
                '<div data-number="%s" class="page-numbers current">%s</div>',
                esc_attr($args['aria_current']),
                $args['before_page_number'].number_format_i18n($n).$args['after_page_number']
            );

            $dots = true;
        else :
            if ($args['show_all'] || ($n <= $end_size || ($current && $n >= $current - $mid_size && $n <= $current + $mid_size) || $n > $total - $end_size)):
                $link = str_replace('%_%', 1 == $n ? '' : $args['format'], $args['base']);
                $link = str_replace('%#%', $n, $link);
                if ($add_args) {
                    $link = add_query_arg($add_args, $link);
                }
                $link .= $args['add_fragment'];

                $page_links[] = sprintf(
                    '<div class="page-numbers" data-number="%s">%s</div>',
                    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
                    $args['before_page_number'].number_format_i18n($n).$args['after_page_number'],
                    $args['before_page_number'].number_format_i18n($n).$args['after_page_number']
                );

                $dots = true;
            elseif ($dots && !$args['show_all']):
                $page_links[] = '<span class="page-numbers dots">'.__('&hellip;').
                    '</span>';

                $dots = false;
            endif;
        endif;
    endfor;

    if ($args['prev_next'] && $current && $current < $total):
        $link = str_replace('%_%', $args['format'], $args['base']);
        $link = str_replace('%#%', $current + 1, $link);
        if ($add_args) {
            $link = add_query_arg($add_args, $link);
        }
        $link .= $args['add_fragment'];

        $page_links[] = sprintf(
            '<div class="arrow" data-number="%s">
    Next <
    /div>',
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
            $current + 1,
            $args['next_text']
        );
    endif;

    switch ($args['type']) {
        case 'array':
            return $page_links;

        case 'list':
            $r .= "<ul class='page-numbers'>\n\t<li>";
            $r .= join("</li>\n\t<li>", $page_links);
            $r .= "</li>\n</ul>\n";
            break;

        default:
            $r .= "<div class='number'>";
            $r .= join("\n", $page_links);
            $r .= "</div>";
            break;
    }

    return $r;
}
```

```html
    <div class="pagination">
      <?php echo ThemeClass::paginate_links(array(
                        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                        'format' => '/page/%#%',
                        'current' => $_GET['page'] ?? 1,
                        'total' => $news->max_num_pages,
                        'prev_text' => __('« prev'),
                        'next_text' => __('next »'),
                    )); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't want to just use the built-in [`paginate_links`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) function and customize it?